# How do I connect my Django App to Postgres Databse?

Tags: django, postgresql

How do I connect my Django App to Postgres Databse?

Whenever I run python manage.py makemigrations after the changes, then I get this kind of error. How can I fix it?

```js
  Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection to server 
at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

  warnings.warn(
No changes detected
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your postgres server is not running. I would suggest you to ensure that postgres server is running and you are able to connect to it.

You can use your terminal or any DB tool like PgAdmin, DBeaver, Tableplus etc.
After you are able to connect to your database through any of the above mentioned ways. Django db connection should not be a problem.

You can take help from

- https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/10/how-to-start-stop-restart-postgresql-server.html
- https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/connecting-postgresql-using-psql-and-pgadmin